# Insert with select and datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm inserting into a table from a temporary table and I need to add date column

```
insert into t1 (date, v1, v2)
select c1, c2 from #temp
```

How can I insert date using this syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the constant/function value in your select. Assuming you want the current date use the following.

```
insert into t1 (date, v1, v2)
select sysdatetime(), c1, c2
from #temp;
```

If you want a specific date, use that.

Comment: `GETDATE()` in SQL Server

Comment: @Charlieface `current_timestamp` is not only supported by SQL Server, but is ANSI compliant too :)

Comment: @Charlieface: `GETDATE` is outdated, since it always returns `DATETIME` - to handle the more recent `DATE` and `DATETIME2(n)` datatype, it's recommended to use `SYSDATETIME()` instead - this returns the proper datatype of whatever variable or column you're storing the value into.

Comment: @marc_s That is not true about return type https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sysdatetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#return-type Quote: "Return Type datetime2(7)"

Comment: @Charlieface : and because of that return type, it can be automagically, silently, and without any loss of precision be converted to any of the datatypes you might desire .....

Comment: @Charlieface how would you use getdate with this statement (insert into + select)?

Comment: @nanquim to use `getdate()` just swap it for `current_timestamp`. The reason for the downvote (which wasn't me), is (hover your mouse over it) either "lack of research" or "not useful to others" as this is a very trivial question, easily answered by a quick google.